# Node js Bull Queue

Tags: node.js, bull

When I create a Bull queue object with out giving name , it will throw the below warning and successfully consumes the job.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:
> The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer,
> Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined
> at Function.from (buffer.js:305:9)

But some times because of this warning the server instance will go into unhealthy state . what will be the exact behaviour ? if queue name is not given, it should not subscribe and publish

Comment: Your function lacks proper error handling. You need to handle the errors thrown by the function which returns a Promise either via `.catch` or wrapping your method in `try/catch` if you are using `async/await`

Comment: that part which I have handled. what is the queue behaviour ? will it consume even without queue name , if it will , how ?